# Slow download speeds of Content in an Android app

Tags: android, html, ibm-cloud

I'm developing a social sharing/community app in html5 for an android phones however the down speeds of Content while scrolling up or down is so slow. Even posting content.

What could be the reason and how can I fix this?

Can this be fixed by Bluemix hosting?

Comment: You have given us no information useful to resolving this.  What are the transactions, how many are there, how big are they, how are they coded, what logs do you have, ...

Comment: This question is impossible to answer; why don't sign up for the free trial they offer and give it a go? Or why don't you post your code for scrolling so we could see if there was anything wrong? Or if you're hosting on a typical $5 per month personal plan, what else did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the server or your connection but mostly it is because of your content.
you can test your page speed using [google page speed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to know if something is wrong with your content.